# Airplay on Raspberry Pi with minimal software

Tags: osmc, shairplay

How can I Airplay to my Raspberry Pi without any software. I am currently using OSMC to do this but all I want to do is be able to Airplay through the Raspberry Pi and onto my stereo through my Emotiva DC-1 DAC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is possible without software. I guess what you mean however is "without installing a full media center". You can just install [Shairplay](https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay) or the now no longer maintained [ShairPort](https://github.com/abrasive/shairport) on your rPi to do the AirPlay emulation.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Note that ShairPort lives on as Shairport-sync https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync